# UniProt survey: Tell us what protein information is important to you

Tags: discussion

Please consider filling in this survey, on behalf of UniProt:

As biological data is growing at an exponential rate, we also have to prioritise the protein information we present. In order to help us provide the data that is important to you, we would be grateful if you could fill in a short survey by Nov 4 2020: https://forms.gle/wM23hdKAvQVnbyYb9 .

Comment: Thanks Elisabeth this is a worth while survey and this is the right place to post it. I will fill this out before the deadline.